# Return smallest value of an array in a function through a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have an array and I would like to return just the lowest value of the array but no matter what I try I get error or I get the full list.  Help

```
function myForEachLoop()

$StudentPopulation = array('BSU'=>19664, 'CSU'=>25500, 'SDSU'=>35887, 'UHM'=>20000,
    'AFA'=>4000, 'UNLV'=>28000, 'FS'=>21389, 'UNR'=>17000, 'UNM'=>25767, 'UW'=>13476);
ksort($StudentPopulation);

foreach($StudentPopulation as $aSchool => $aPop)
    {
    $output .= '<strong>School:</strong> ' . ($aSchool) . '<strong> Population:</strong> ' . $aPop . '<br />';
}
return $output;
```

I want to return just "School:  AFA"  Population: 4000".

Comment: have you tried using php  min($array) ?

Comment: After you sort the array, just get the first element, don't loop over the whole array.

Comment: is it some kind of school test assignment for you?

Comment: This is for work.  My manager expected me to figure it out and told me to "put it in a foreach loop".  After an embarrassing amount of time of trial and error I sought help and am so thankful I did!  Obviously it's part of much larger project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has almost no sense, but if you really need it to be done try:

```
function myForEachLoop(&$StudentPopulation) {
ksort($StudentPopulation);
$min = 'NO_MIN';
foreach($StudentPopulation as $aSchool => $aPop)
    {
    if($min=='NO_MIN' || $aPop<$min) {
    $output = '<strong>School:</strong> ' . ($aSchool) . '<strong> Population:</strong> ' . $aPop . '<br />';
    $min = $aPop;
    }
}
return $output;
}

$StudentPopulation = array('BSU'=>19664, 'CSU'=>25500, 'SDSU'=>35887, 'UHM'=>20000,
    'AFA'=>4000, 'UNLV'=>28000, 'FS'=>21389, 'UNR'=>17000, 'UNM'=>25767, 'UW'=>13476);
echo myForEachLoop($StudentPopulation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myForEachLoop()
{

$StudentPopulation = array('BSU'=>19664, 'CSU'=>25500, 'SDSU'=>35887, 'UHM'=>20000,
    'AFA'=>4000, 'UNLV'=>28000, 'FS'=>21389, 'UNR'=>17000, 'UNM'=>25767, 'UW'=>13476);
ksort($StudentPopulation);


$lowestValue = min($studentPopulation); // 4000
$lowestValueIndex = array_keys($studentPopulation, min($studentPopulation)); //  AFA


$output .= '<strong>School:</strong> ' . ($lowestValueIndex) . '<strong> Population:</strong> ' . $lowestValue. '<br />'

return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That works but am told I need to get it done using a foreach loop. Ideas?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't HAVE to be a foreach loop.  It just needs to be a loop of some kind.

Comment: If you have to get it done using a loop, ask whoever has set this limitation why you have to do it inefficiently.